# Java code check

Tags: java

The purpose of my program was to check the code which user input, then to tell whether this code is correct or not. I created `splitCode` method manually in order to get each word from the user then I'm making not equal these words to array[index] with using if , but i'm having problems with { },(),"",[]... and other characters.I couldn't compare them

```
    void syntaxcheck( ){
    String input  =  text2Level1.getText();
    String[] arr = splitCode(input);

    int counter=0;
    String errorLog = " ";

  if(!"public".equals(arr[0])){
    errorLog += "Please check your public\n";
     text3Level1.setText(errorLog);  
     }

     if(!"class".equals(arr[1])){
       errorLog += "Please check your static\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);           
     }

     if(!"HelloWorld".equals(arr[2])){
       errorLog += "Please check your void\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);           
     }

     if(!"public".equals(arr[3])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String1\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }       

     if(!"static".equals(arr[4])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String2\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }

     if(!"void".equals(arr[5])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String3\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }

     if(!"main".equals(arr[6])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String4\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }       

     if(!"String".equals(arr[7])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String6\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }




     if(!"args".equals(arr[8])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String9\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }


     if(!"System.out.println".equals(arr[9])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String12\n";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }



     if(!"\"".equals(arr[10])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String18";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }

     if(!"HelloWorld".equals(arr[11])){
       errorLog += "Please check your String19";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);
     }



     if(!"\"".equals(arr[12])){
       errorLog += "Please check your args20";
      text3Level1.setText(errorLog);

     }





     if("public".equals(arr[0])){

        counter++;  
         }



         if("class".equals(arr[1])){
          counter++;

         }

         if("HelloWorld".equals(arr[2])){

             counter++;
         }





         if("public".equals(arr[3])){
             counter++;
         }


         if("static".equals(arr[4])){
             counter++;
         }

         if("void".equals(arr[5])){
             counter++;
         }

         if("main".equals(arr[6])){
             counter++;
         }



         if("String".equals(arr[7])){
             counter++;
         }




         if("args".equals(arr[8])){
             counter++;
         }


         if("System.out.println".equals(arr[9])){
             counter++;
         }



         if("\"".equals(arr[10])){
             counter++;
         }

         if("HelloWorld".equals(arr[11])){
             counter++;
         }



         if("\"".equals(arr[12])){
             counter++;

         }



     if(text3Level1.getText().equals(null)){
         backPanelLevel1.setVisible(false);

       }  

     if ( counter==13 ) {

         text3Level1.setText("Congratulations Ahmed");
         }

       System.out.println(counter);

      }




     static String[] splitCode(String text){
       ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

       String temp = "";
       for(int n = 0; n < text.length(); n++){
           if(text.charAt(n) != ' ' && text.charAt(n) != '\n' && text.charAt(n) != '\t' && text.charAt(n) != '{'
                     && text.charAt(n) != '}' && text.charAt(n) != '[' && text.charAt(n) != ']' && text.charAt(n) != '('
                     && text.charAt(n) != ')')
           temp += text.charAt(n);
         else{
           if(!temp.equals("")){

             arr.add(temp);
           }
           temp = "";
         }
       }
       if(!temp.equals(""))
         arr.add(temp);

       String[] s = new String[arr.size()];
       for(int n = 0; n < arr.size(); n++)
         s[n] = arr.get(n);
       return s;  

     }
   }
```

Comment: you should use Regular Expression and then use String.split(regex)    (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: my head hurts trying to read that question

Comment: could you please simplify the problem statement

Comment: If I get correctly what you are trying to achieve then you should definitely look into what are grammars and parsing and how it is done.

Comment: You should research lexers and parsers.